# Django: serve static section of a web-app

Tags: django, nginx

I have:

- a Django web app
- a separate static HTML site (blog)

The static site is a separate directory tree.

I want the **static site** to be served as a sub-section of the web app.

For example, the app is at `http://app.com/` and the static is site served from `http://app.com/blog`

Here's my `/etc/nginx/sites-available/app`:

```
upstream app_server {
    server 127.0.0.1:9000 fail_timeout=0;
}

server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server ipv6only=on;

    ...

    location / {
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_redirect off;
            proxy_buffering off;
            proxy_pass http://app_server;
    }
}
```

Comment: You can setup a seperate location for /blog and proxy it to your static site.

Comment: @BipulJain so is it just nginx configuration or do I need to touch django?

Comment: @astreltsov include your current nginx configuration for detail answer, check my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
server  {
  server_name yourdomain.com;
  location /blog{
     root /path/to/static/html;
  }

  location /{
     # your django app configuration
     proxy_pass http://localhost:8000$request_uri;
     # other configurations
  }
}
```

Comment: also I forgot to **restart nginx** after this